# How do I compare strings in GoLang?

Tags: go

I am unable to produce a 'true' result when it comes to Go string comparison. I wrote the following to explain the issue and attached a screenshot of the output

```
// string comparison in Go
package main
import "fmt"
import "bufio"
import "os"

func main() {
    var isLetterA bool 

    fmt.Println("Enter the letter a")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    if(input == "a") {
        isLetterA = true
    } else {
        isLetterA = false 
    }

    fmt.Println("You entered",input)
    fmt.Println("Is it the letter a?",isLetterA)

}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 164, accepted):

`==` is the correct operator to compare strings in Go. However, the strings that you read from STDIN with `reader.ReadString` do not contain `"a"`, but `"a\n"` (if you look closely, you'll see the extra line break in your example output).

You can use the [`strings.TrimRight`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimRight) function to remove trailing whitespaces from your input:

```
if strings.TrimRight(input, "\n") == "a" {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 14):

For the Platform Independent Users or Windows users, what you can do is:

import runtime:

```
import (
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)
```

and then trim the string like this:

```
if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
  input = strings.TrimRight(input, "\r\n")
} else {
  input = strings.TrimRight(input, "\n")
}
```

now you can compare it like that:

```
if strings.Compare(input, "a") == 0 {
  //....yourCode
}
```

This is a better approach when you're making use of STDIN on multiple platforms.

## Explanation

This happens because on windows lines end with `"\r\n"` which is known as CRLF, but on UNIX lines end with `"\n"` which is known as LF and that's why we trim `"\n"` on unix based operating systems while we trim `"\r\n"` on windows.

Comment: There's no need to differentiate. The second argument is a cutset, not a suffix, and any characters in the cutset will be trimmed, in any order/combination. Trimming "\r\n" will suffice on both.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming there are no prepending/succeeding whitespace characters, there are still a few ways to assert string equality. Some of those are:

- [`strings.ToLower(..)`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ToLower) then `==`
- [`strings.EqualFold(.., ..)`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#example_EqualFold)
- [`cases#Lower`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/cases#Lower) paired with `==`
- [`cases#Fold`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/cases#Fold) paired with `==`

Here are some basic benchmark results (in these tests, `strings.EqualFold(.., ..)` seems like the most performant choice):

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkStringOps/both_strings_equal::equality_op-4               10000        182944 ns/op
BenchmarkStringOps/both_strings_equal::strings_equal_fold-4        10000        114371 ns/op
BenchmarkStringOps/both_strings_equal::fold_caser-4                10000       2599013 ns/op
BenchmarkStringOps/both_strings_equal::lower_caser-4               10000       3592486 ns/op

BenchmarkStringOps/one_string_in_caps::equality_op-4               10000        417780 ns/op
BenchmarkStringOps/one_string_in_caps::strings_equal_fold-4        10000        153509 ns/op
BenchmarkStringOps/one_string_in_caps::fold_caser-4                10000       3039782 ns/op
BenchmarkStringOps/one_string_in_caps::lower_caser-4               10000       3861189 ns/op

BenchmarkStringOps/weird_casing_situation::equality_op-4           10000        619104 ns/op
BenchmarkStringOps/weird_casing_situation::strings_equal_fold-4    10000        148489 ns/op
BenchmarkStringOps/weird_casing_situation::fold_caser-4            10000       3603943 ns/op
BenchmarkStringOps/weird_casing_situation::lower_caser-4           10000       3637832 ns/op
```

Since there are quite a few options, so here's the code to generate benchmarks.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "testing"

    "golang.org/x/text/cases"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
)

func BenchmarkStringOps(b *testing.B) {
    foldCaser := cases.Fold()
    lowerCaser := cases.Lower(language.English)

    tests := []struct{
        description string
        first, second string
    }{
        {
            description: "both strings equal",
            first: "aaaa",
            second: "aaaa",
        },
        {
            description: "one string in caps",
            first: "aaaa",
            second: "AAAA",
        },
        {
            description: "weird casing situation",
            first: "aAaA",
            second: "AaAa",
        },
    }

    for _, tt := range tests {
        b.Run(fmt.Sprintf("%s::equality op", tt.description), func(b *testing.B) {
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                benchmarkStringEqualsOperation(tt.first, tt.second, b)
            }
        })

        b.Run(fmt.Sprintf("%s::strings equal fold", tt.description), func(b *testing.B) {
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                benchmarkStringsEqualFold(tt.first, tt.second, b)
            }
        })

        b.Run(fmt.Sprintf("%s::fold caser", tt.description), func(b *testing.B) {
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                benchmarkStringsFoldCaser(tt.first, tt.second, foldCaser, b)
            }
        })

        b.Run(fmt.Sprintf("%s::lower caser", tt.description), func(b *testing.B) {
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                benchmarkStringsLowerCaser(tt.first, tt.second, lowerCaser, b)
            }
        })
    }
}

func benchmarkStringEqualsOperation(first, second string, b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = strings.ToLower(first) == strings.ToLower(second)
    }
}

func benchmarkStringsEqualFold(first, second string, b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = strings.EqualFold(first, second)
    }
}

func benchmarkStringsFoldCaser(first, second string, caser cases.Caser, b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = caser.String(first) == caser.String(second)
    }
}

func benchmarkStringsLowerCaser(first, second string, caser cases.Caser, b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = caser.String(first) == caser.String(second)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The content inside strings in Golang can be compared using `==` operator. If the results are not as expected there may be some hidden characters like `\n`, `\r`, spaces, etc. So as a general rule of thumb, try removing those using functions provided by `strings` package in golang.

For Instance, spaces can be removed using `strings.TrimSpace` function. You can also define a custom function to remove any character you need. `strings.TrimFunc` function can give you more power.