# Unable to correctly compare two strings in go

Tags: string, go

Hi I am trying to find the no. of times a digit appears in a no. using the below code. But the value of j is always 0 even if the digit appears many time in the number. I would like to know why the current comparison does not work. Is it possible to do this without converting input to integer?

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "bufio"
import "os"

func main (){

reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
c,_ := reader.ReadString('\n')
d,_ := reader.ReadString('\n')


j := 0
for _,i := range(c){
    if string(i) == d{
        fmt.Printf("inside if")
        j = j+1
    }
}
fmt.Println(j)

}
```

Comment: See [How do I compare strings in GoLang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34383705/5728991).  The variable `d` includes the `\n` delimiter.  The runes in `c` do not include the delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `func (b *Reader) ReadString(delim byte) (string, error)`
>
> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data *up to and including the delimiter*.

So if you enter `3` for `d`, then `d == "3\n"`.

You probably just need to do:

```
d,_ := reader.ReadString('\n')
d = d[:len(d)-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked. After reading further I found out same could be achieved by using TrimSpace from strings so I am using that one